# Google Analytics shows no data under demographics and interest

Tags: google-analytics

The company I work for has created a online store site with Wix. I am in charge of maintaining the site. We have one problem: although some other stuff like the traffic is displaying nicely but there is no data for interest and demographic overview.

Any fix to this issue?

[image]